# I accidentally flagged a question. How do I notify moderators to disregard (or do I bother)?

Tags: discussion, flags

I accidentally flagged a question. How do I notify moderators to disregard (or do I bother)? I know they are busy but also don't want them to have to go through a bogus flag because I clicked in the wrong tab.

Comment: Dunno, if it works, but you could flag it again with a custom message saying, "I screwed up. Please ignore my other flag." I'm not sure whether the mod is supposed to validate or decline it, but at least it stops the mod from wasting his/her time trying to figure out what to do with the original flag.

Comment: @Mystical you can't flag questions twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was always told to drop a note in chat.. but I don't think it's a big deal since they either have to approve your flag or dismiss it, and they can't very well approve a bad flag even if it was only an accident.

Comment: Yep, don't bother, let it go. There may be a very slight penalty for having your flag dismissed as unhelpful, but you shouldn't worry about that. And just for reference there is no guarantee that the same mod would process consecutive flags from the same user, so don't use them as a way of messaging the mods.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I don't care about the rep, I just didn't want a good question being flagged as a duplicate when I meant to flag the other one.